# Get PID of process blocking a COM PORT

Tags: c#, python, windows, serial-port

How to go about to get the process id of a process blocking a certain COM Port on Windows 7 and/or later?

I would like to get the PID programmatically. If possible using Python or C# but the language is not really important, I just want to understand the procedure.

Comment: What have you tried so far? A.K.A Why is this an SO question and not a google query?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So far I've only been able to list all ports from the registry. Unfortunately google didn't help me much, however I'm not too familiar with the windows OS. Any pointers suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked numerous times on SO and many other forums for the last 10 years or so. The generally accepted answer is to use sysinternals to find the process using the particular file handle. Remember, a serial port is really just a file as far as the win32 api is concerned.

So, two answers for you:

1. Use sysinternals to find to offending application. I don't think this approach will work via python but you might hack something with .NET.
2. Use the NtQuerySystemInformation in a getHandles function. Take a look at the structures and figure out which fields are useful for identifying the offending process.
3. os.system("taskkill blah blah blah") against known serial port using apps. More on this idea at the end.

The 2nd idea sounds fun, however I just don't think the juice is worth the squeeze in this case. A relatively small number of processes actually use serial ports these days and if you are working in a specific problem domain, you are well aware of what the applications are called.

I would just run taskkill (via os.system) against any applications that I know 1) can be safely closed and 2) might actually have a port open. With this approach you'll save the headache of enumerating file handles and get back to focusing on what your application should really be doing.